# Underline needed using Phantom for cells in Tables

Tags: tables, underline, phantom

Underline need to set selected Cell using phantom text(not cell width) so that I do not want to change Column alignment?
Is any way to achieve this? Kindly ignore my \al definitions. Please find MWE file:

```
\documentclass{book}


\makeatletter

\def\al#1#2{\underline{\phantom{#1}\makebox[0pt][r]{#2}}}

%\def\bl#1#2#3#4{\def\@thirdarg{#1}\ifx\@thirdarg\@empty\underline{\makebox[r][#4]{#2}}\else\underline{\makebox[#3][#4]{#2}}\fi}

\makeatother



\begin{document}




\bigskip\bigskip
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
1000&1000&\al{Sample}{1000}\\
500&500&\al{Sample}{500}\\
10&10&\al{Sample}{10}\\
1&1&\al{Sample}{2}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
1000&1000&{1000}\\
500&500&{500}\\
10&10&{10}\\
1&1&{2}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: We need underline for selected cell content but underline should be extend what
we have given in the \phantom{sdfdsf sdf}.

Comment: Does `500&500&\al{1000}{500}\\ ` give you the desired result?

Comment: Yes, but column alignment I have given as left but current output as right alignment. Can we do this without \makebox command because it require alignment and width, my requirement underline should be extend without given \makebox command.

Comment: Like this? `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
1000&1000&\underline{1000}\\
500&500&\underline{500\phantom{0}}\\
10&10&\underline{10\phantom{00}}\\
1&1&\underline{2\phantom{000}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}`

Comment: Last column each cell have different width numbers, but equal width of underline needed for last column, can we simplify using two argument macros as like \al command?

Comment: Probably like the folowing: `\newcommand{\myul}[2]{\underline{#1\phantom{#2}}}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
1000&1000&\myul{1000}{}\\
500&500&\myul{500}{0}\\
10&10&\myul{10}{00}\\
1&1&\myul{2}{000}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}`

Comment: Yes output like this, but problem is that 
I need to give phantom character for each cell based on number of characters 
in the cell, in my book there were 500+ Accounts table and need to give
fixed underline width.

Comment: I expected following code using macros:
FIRST COLUMN 
\myul{phantomextra}{1000}
\myul{phantomextra}{100}
\myul{phantomextra}{10}SECOND COLUMN 
\myul{phantom}{10}
\myul{phantom}{10}
\myul{phantom}{1}THIRD COLUMN
\myul{phantomextraxx}{10000000000}
\myul{phantomextraxx}{10}
\myul{phantomextraxx}{100000}

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested tabulars and `\hline` to archive the underlining. I used left aligned, fixed width `w`-column from [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array), but `p{<wd>}`-columns will also work. I added `\extrarowheigth` to avoid collisions between `\hline` and the cell content:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
1000&1000&\begin{tabular}{@{}wl{0.8cm}@{}}
1000\\\hline
\end{tabular}\\
500&500& \begin{tabular}{@{}wl{0.8cm}@{}}
500\\\hline
\end{tabular}\\
10&10& \begin{tabular}{@{}wl{0.8cm}@{}}
10\\\hline
\end{tabular}\\
1&1& \begin{tabular}{@{}wl{0.8cm}@{}}
2\\\hline
\end{tabular}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```